# Measuring the percentage of a given color in an area?

Tags: image-processing

Given this image I would like to measure how much (in percentage relative to the square area) of each black delimited square is filled with green:

```
i = Import["http://i.imgur.com/62buGws.png"]
```

[image]

I am a bit lost with the usage of the image processing functions.  It seems like [`MorphologicalPerimeter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalPerimeter.html)and [`PixelValuePositions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PixelValuePositions.html)or [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageData.html)could be useful.

If I can find a way to detect each square then it is a matter of calling `ImageData` on that area and count the number of green pixels.

Any tips please?

Comment: Does it need to count only the exact color defined by its RGB value? This could cause problems with jpg and other lossy formats.

Comment: The original image is a PDF file but for some reason Mathematica gave me an error when using Import["image.pdf"] and trying to use the resulting image with the PixelValuePositions function. The error was "PixelValuePositions::imginv: Expecting an image or a graphics instead of...".  So I converted it to a PNG. Is it possible to weight the pixels according to the intensity of green?

Comment: It is certainly possible. But if the pdf consists of shapes, you might be able to extract the dimensions of green rectangles and calculate percentages from that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Update to account for multiple box sets on a single page

In order to extract the box information from a set of boxes, two tweaks were needed.  First, I needed to explicitly state an `ImageSize` to get the desired resolution.  Second, I needed to adjust the `Binarize` critereon so that the boxes, which are now surrounded by grey borders, could be identified by `MorphologicalComponents`.

```
i = Image[
   First@Import[
     "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8003134/grid2.pdf", 
     "Pages"], ImageSize -> 2500];
boxes = ComponentMeasurements[
   MorphologicalComponents[
    Binarize[i, 
     And[#[[1]] < 0.75, #[[2]] < 0.75, #[[3]] < 
        0.75] &]], {"BoundingBox", "Centroid"}];
centers = (Range@Length@boxes /. boxes)[[All, 2]];
dims = (Range@Length@boxes /. boxes)[[All, 1]];
intensity = 
  1 - ImageMeasurements[
      ImageTake[i, 
       ImageDimensions[i][[2]] - {#[[2, 2]], #[[1, 2]]}, {#[[1, 
          1]], #[[2, 1]]}], "MeanIntensity"] & /@ dims;
intensity = Rescale[intensity, {Min[intensity], Max[intensity]}];
Show[i, Epilog -> 
  Table[Text[NumberForm[intensity[[i]], {1, 2}], centers[[i]]], {i, 
    Length@boxes}]]
```

The resulting image is too big to display.  Instead, here is a cropped image showing the complete upper-left hand set of boxes and bits of the neighboring boxes to demonstrate that the code is working.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some additional tweaking of the code will be necessary if you want to get precision better than about 5%.  My first suggestion would be to raise the image size even further and fine tune the Binarize criteria.

Note that replacing `First` with `Last` in the definition of `i` should get you the second page.

### Old approach

*This works for a pdf containing a single set of boxes*

Here's another approach that makes use of `ComponentMeasurements`

```
i = Image[
   First@Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8003134/img.pdf",
      "Pages"]];
boxes = ComponentMeasurements[
   MorphologicalComponents[
    Binarize[i, #[[1]] == #[[2]] == #[[3]] == 0 &]], {"BoundingBox", 
    "Centroid"}];
centers = (Range@Length@boxes /. boxes)[[All, 2]];
dims = (Range@Length@boxes /. boxes)[[All, 1]];
intensity = 
  1 - ImageMeasurements[
      ImageTake[i, 
       ImageDimensions[i][[2]] - {#[[2, 2]], #[[1, 2]]}, {#[[1, 
          1]], #[[2, 1]]}], "MeanIntensity"] & /@ dims;
intensity = Rescale[intensity, {Min[intensity], Max[intensity]}];
Show[i, Epilog -> 
  Table[Text[intensity[[i]], centers[[i]]], {i, Length@boxes}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First, I find the squares in the image with `MorphologicalComponents`.  I use the dimensions extracted from `ComponentMeasurements` to `ImageTake` each square.  To determine the amount of green in the square, I use `ImageMeasurements` which won't give a 0 for the completely empty box since I've made no effort to remove the bounding black line.  I resolve this issue by rescaling the intensity, assuming that there is a completely filled and completely empty box.  Finally, since there are already answers showing how one extracts the values into a table, I use the "Centroid" from `ComponentMeasurements` to `Show` the values over the original image.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A looked at MorphologicalComponents and ComponentMeasurements but didn't know how to use it.

Comment: I normally don't vote for answers I cannot test, and I don't have `ComponentMeasurements` in version 7, but I like the overlaid values so much you get a +1 anyway.

Comment: I tried to apply your code to this PDF: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8003134/grid2.pdf but boxes will return an empty list. How can I apply the procedure  to this file? Thanks.

Comment: @dabd are you rasterizing the graphic with `Image` before you attempt the manipulation?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes I am using the code as shown above where it calls Image. When I evaluate this sub-expression for the new pdf (dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8003134/grid2.pdf) MorphologicalComponents[
    Binarize[i, #[[1]] == #[[2]] == #[[3]] == 0 &]] it returns a huge list of lists with only zeros.

Comment: Your new PDF is sufficiently different from the first version that it is no surprise that it doesn't work.  The original image has isolated boxes with black borders; the new image is a series of boxes with grey borders.  Changing the Binarize condition to And[#[[1]] < 0.3, #[[2]] < 0.3, #[[3]] < 0.3] & helps, see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f85mq.png), but we are still left with non-separated boxes so my code won't work without modification.

Comment: Thanks again for the trouble of adapting the solution!

Answer (score 9):

Since your image elements are of uniform size on a rectangular grid you can use [`ImageParition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageParition.html) to split them apart, and then a combination of [`ImageCrop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCrop.html) and [`ImageTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageTake.html) to get just the internal areas.  From there you can use `ImageData` to access the raster, and [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tally.html) to count the pixels by color.

Example:

```
count = Tally[Join @@ ImageData @ ImageCrop @ #] &;

i = Import["http://i.imgur.com/62buGws.png"];

cells = ImagePartition[i, {48, 48}, {50, 50}];

Map[count, cells, {2}][[2, 3]]
```

> ```
> {{{0.188235, 0.188235, 0.188235}, 2}, {{0., 0., 0.}, 176}, {{1., 1., 1.},
> ```
>
> 616}, {{0.74902, 1., 0.74902}, 44}, {{0., 1., 0.}, 
>     1276}, {{0.0470588, 0.0627451, 0.0470588}, 2}}

`[[2, 3]]` is to look at the square on the second row, third column. (The first row is blank.)

These are the tallies of the RGB values for each cell, including the black border. `{{0.74902, 1., 0.74902}, 44}` is the row of light green pixels on the margin between green and white.  You'll have to decide how you want to count these.  You can then process the values accordingly.  This is a general approach since it counts all colors in the cell; you can find specific ratios, etc., using that data.

To count green pixels, defined as RGB values where G equals 1, weighted by saturation, we could use:

```
green = Tr @ Cases[#, {{x_, o_ /; o == 1, x_}, c_} :> (1 - x) c] &;
```

The `Condition` `o_ /; o == 1` is used rather than the simpler `1.` to make the match more robust.

Now:

```
dat = Map[Composition[green, count], Rest @ cells, {2}];

dat // First
```

> ```
> {0., 1936., 1287.04, 1936., 1936., 1440.96, 1243.04, 1452.,
>     902.086, 956.957, 956.957, 924., 968.}
> ```

If we know a priori the inside dimensions of each cell to be 44*44 we can find the ratio of green to white with:

```
dat / 44^2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

ybeltukov uses a similar method that is more optimized for this particular operation, but I feel that using the image processing functions such as `ImagePartition` and `ImageCrop` offer additional features that you may find valuable in other applications, for example if each cell were to have a different size.

*Edit:* actually ybeltukov's code is not presently accurate because it does not use e.g. `ImageCrop` and it is not counting only the pixels inside the box.

Comment: Regarding the counting of the light shaded green squares is it possible to count them with a weight proportional to the green intensity,  where RGBColor(0,1,0) would weight 1? What is the meaning of the cropping specifications {2,-2} and {2,-2}?

Comment: @dabd I had to leave right after I wrote this so I didn't really finish it.  Yes, I will show how to add that weighting and complete the count.  The `ImageTake` operation was used to remove the black border, but we could also do without that operation and use the ratio of green to white squares only.  I'll see which makes for simpler code and update my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed explanations and solutions!

Answer (score 7):

Note that your comment about the file being a PDF instead of a PNG changes the question, in that there ways to process a PDF that you cannot do to PNG.

First import the `"Pages"` of the PDF and stored the first (and only) one in `i`:

```
i = First @ Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8003134/img.pdf", "Pages"];
```

Now the image is in fact scalable `Graphics` and the black squares and green rectangles are stored as [`JoinedCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinedCurve.html) and [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html) objects:

```
Cases[i, _JoinedCurve, Infinity, 1]
Cases[i, _FilledCurve, Infinity, 1]
(*
   {JoinedCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}},
                {{{2., 647.}, {47., 647.}, {47., 602.}, {2., 602.}}},
                CurveClosed -> {1}]}
   {FilledCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}},
                {{{2., 597.}, {47., 597.}, {47., 552.}, {2., 552.}}}]}
*)
```

Note that the coordinates of the squares and rectangles are in the second argument.

Also upon inspection, the squares are stored in order by columns. So we can extract the squares, Partition them, and map the coordinates of a corner to the index of the square.  The green rectangles share two of the coordinates with its enclosing square, so we pick a corner in common to both (the 4th coordinate).  We can get the area of a green rectangle by subtracting the coordinates of opposite corners and multiplying, and store then as rules mapping corner to areas.  We can get the total area of a square the same way.

```
corner2idx = With[{squares = Cases[i, JoinedCurve[_, {rect_}, ___] :> rect, Infinity]},
   Flatten @ MapIndexed[#[[4]] -> Reverse[#2] &, Partition[squares, 13], {2}]];

corner2area = With[{green = Cases[i, FilledCurve[_, {rect_}, ___] :> rect, Infinity]},
   #[[4]] -> Times @@ First@Differences[#[[{2, 4}]]] & /@ green];

totalArea = 
 Times @@ First @ Differences[
   Cases[i, JoinedCurve[_, {rect_}, ___] :> rect, Infinity, 1][[1, {2, 4}]]]
(*
   2025.
*)
```

Now we can put it all together, using the rules `corner2idx` that map corner coordinates to indices to create a list of array rules that map the index to the corresponding area.  Dividing by the total area gives the proportion of green in each square.

```
proportions = SparseArray[corner2area /. corner2idx, {13, 13}, 0.]/totalArea;

Round[proportions, 0.02] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the literate programming style explanation. I will have to study your code because I am not familiar with some functions and syntax you are using.

Answer (score 5):

One can use [`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html) here

```
a = ImageData[Import["http://i.imgur.com/62buGws.png"]][[50 ;;, All, 1]];

p = Developer`PartitionMap[Total[#, 2] &, a, {50, 50}, 50, 1, 0];
p = Max[p] - p;
p = Round[p/Max[p], 0.01];

p // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I use the red channel because the green channel is the same for green and white areas.

Comment: This looks excellent! Thanks. One question: my original file is in PDF but if I use your code with it Mathematica issues an error. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8003134/img.pdf  How can I import it? Thanks.

Comment: This does not appear to be accurate; unless I am mistaken you are not counting only the pixels inside the boxes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It adds a constant which I remove by `Max[p] - p`. There is a small errors because of the rasterization problems (especially in the last column).

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way is using `HistogramList` and `PixelValuePositions`:

This will give an idea of why and that it works:

```
i = ImageCrop@Import["http://i.imgur.com/62buGws.png"];
Histogram3D[
 PixelValuePositions[i, Green], {12, 12}
 ]
```

[image: histogram]

`Histogram3D` uses `HistogramList` to gather the data. To generate the matrix the other answers have been able to generate we can do this:

```
N@(44 44)^-1 Reverse@Transpose@HistogramList[
      PixelValuePositions[i, Green], {12, 12}][[2]] // MatrixForm
```

`44 44` is the size of one square.

Comment: Very nice! thanks